# Unable to perform "flutter doctor --android-licenses" command after following other stack posts

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I'm trying to run this command `flutter doctor --android-licenses` since I have this as an error upon running `flutter doctor`.

I've downloaded Java 8 and updated my environment variables. I've also installed the "Android SDK Command-line Tool" on Android Studio. When I run the command `flutter doctor --android-licenses`, I still get these errors:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/prefs/AndroidLocationsProvider has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" Android sdkmanager tool was found, but failed to run
(C:\Users\simer\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\sdkmanager.bat): "exited code 1".
Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK,
visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions.
```

Should I try re-installing Android Studio? I'm not sure what it means to re-install or update my Android SDK. If I do re-install everything related to Android Studio (I downloaded this a couple of years back before I set up Flutter), do I have to re-setup flutter again?